# Select unique values in dataframe based on sorted value

Tags: r, sorting, filter, dplyr, data.table

Has anyone selected unique values from a dataframe based on a second value's highest value?

Example:

```
name value
cheese 15
pepperoni 12
cheese 9
tomato 4
cheese 3
tomato 2
```

The best I've come up with - which I am SURE there's a better way - is to sort df by value descending, extract df$name, run unique() on that, then do a left join back with dplyr.

The ideal outcome is this:

```
name value
cheese 15
pepperoni 12
tomato 4
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seeing your expected result, for each `name`, you are looking for the row that has the largest number. One way to achieve this task is the following.

```
library(dplyr)
group_by(mydf, name) %>%
slice(which.max(value))

# A tibble: 3 x 2
# Groups:   name [3]
#  name      value
#  <fct>     <int>
#1 cheese       15
#2 pepperoni    12
#3 tomato        4
```

DATA

```
mydf <- structure(list(name = structure(c(1L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 3L), .Label = c("cheese", 
"pepperoni", "tomato"), class = "factor"), value = c(15L, 12L, 
9L, 4L, 3L, 2L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -6L
))
```

Comment: That's so much simpler than what I was trying to do - thank you!

Comment: @ChristopherPenn Pleasure to help you.